# How do you select multiple text regions in a Word document using an office add-in

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

Using the javascript API for Office, how can you select multiple phrases in a document like so?:

[image]

It seems to be fairly easy to reformat the text, but how do you non-destructively indicate (select or squiggly underline) phrases

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: What code would you like? I am essentially asking if this functionality is available in the API.

Comment: You ask for "highlight" in the title and in your first sentence - that is a technical term in Word - and the answer Markus gave you. And it's  what you show in your screen shot. You need to describe exactly what you mean - we can't read your mind. Word only supports multiple selections (real selections) by the user, not through any code interface. Highlighting is exactly what Word uses internally to display "multiple selections" performed using its Find functionality.

Comment: Sincere apologies all round for rubbing everybody up the wrong way. I see now that "highlight" is a semantically challenging word, so I will edit the question to use the term "show multiple selections". And no, style manipulation isn't a solution.

Comment: I repeat:  Word only supports multiple selections (real selections) by the user, not through any code interface. Highlighting (what your screen shot shows) is exactly what Word, itsefl, uses internally to display "multiple selections" performed using its Find functionality. What you want to do isn't supported by Word - not by VBA, not by Office JS, nor any other programming interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discontinuous selections is neither supported in the API not in other platforms like Online. Also wavy underlines, who will be the answer for your scenario given is non-dirtying document behavior, are not yet supported but in our backlog.

So your only option in the API is to use our search method who returns a collection of ranges, then traverse it and change the highlight. The challenge here is that you need to remember the ranges to you can restore its original formatting if so needed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a span tag for the hightlighting area and give some CSS style like "background:yellow".

Since you have no code example provided, this is just a limited answer, but you should get the idea.

```
 <style>
     span.hilight { background: yellow; }
 </style>

 <div>Lorem <span class="hilight">ipsum</span> is my favorite text.</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am wondering how to non-destructively "select" the text, not how to change the formatting.

Comment: You also asked for highlighting. I am wondering why the downvote. Your question has no code to correct or to supply more info.

Comment: Word highlights and underlines regions when using tools such as "find", and "spellcheck". The question is whether this "highlighting" can be triggered from within the js API. Its a shame that the question is now downvoted, as it is a reasonable thing to ask, and will help others if answered.